# CoreData fetch request to fetch CKRecord encoded with `CKRecord.encodeSystemFields`

Tags: core-data, cloudkit

Say I have managed object with property `systemFields` in which CKRecord system fields are encoded.

How efficiently query previously saved entity using `CKRecord` which I got say from Subscription notification?

Is it possible to setup predicate for `NSFetchRequest` to query existing CoreData entity `by CKRecord`?

```
class FailureCDEntity: NSManagedObject {

   @NSManaged private (set) var summaryDescription: String
   @NSManaged private (set) var creationDate: Date
   @NSManaged private (set) var systemFields: Data

   convenience init(record: CKRecord, in context: NSManagedObjectContext) throws {
      try self.init(in: context)
      systemFields = record.encode()
      ...
   }
}
```

Extension for CKRecord:

```
extension CKRecord {

   func encode() -> Data {
      let data = NSMutableData()
      let archiver = NSKeyedArchiver(forWritingWith: data)
      archiver.requiresSecureCoding = true
      encodeSystemFields(with: archiver)
      archiver.finishEncoding()
      return data as Data
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Predicates for binary fields have the same restrictions as other kinds of fields, but the binary nature makes them harder to construct. If you can be sure that your `encode()` method will produce **exactly** the same result for the stored object and the one from the notification, you can use a trivial predicate that just matches the value of `systemFields`. If not, your only options depend on knowing the details of the binary encoding. Can you use a "starts with" predicate? Maybe an "ends with"? It's impossible to say without knowing how to match up values based on a subset of the binary representation.

For this reason, predicates that depend on a binary field are difficult or impossible to use. If you can describe how to match values *based on the binary encoding*, you can probably come up with a predicate to implement that. Otherwise, some other technique will be needed. I'm not familiar enough with `CKRecord` to say what that is. Maybe store the record ID and match on that?

Comment: Thanks! More reading shows that we seems have no other way as to store additional properties in addition to `systemFields` in order to fetch efficiently.  https://nickharris.wordpress.com/2016/02/09/cloudkit-core-data-nsoperations-introduction/